# R: Using Regex To Recognizes Spaces

Tags: r, regex, string, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
id = 1:3
var= c("123 river street A1B 6L2", "124 ocean road g7u 6p2 apartment number 5", "apartment 6 k8b 7Ji"   )
my_data = data.frame(id, var)

  id                                       var
1  1                  123 river street A1B 6L2
2  2 124 ocean road g7u 6p2 apartment number 5
3  3                       apartment 6 k8b 7Ji
```

I am trying to get the following output - I would like to remove the spaces between the alpha-numeric sequences in each row:

```
  id                                       var no_space  spaces                                var_final
1  1                  123 river street A1B 6L2  A1B 6L2  A1B6L2                  123 river street A1B6L2
2  2 124 ocean road g7u 6p2 apartment number 5  g7u 6p2  g7u6p2 124 ocean road g7u6p2 apartment number 5
3  3                       apartment 6 k8b 7Ji  k8b 7Ji  k8b7Ji                       apartment 6 k8b7Ji
```

I know how to begin this in an indirect way:

```
spaces = apply(my_data, 1, function(x) gsub('(([A-Z] ?[0-9]){3})|.', '\\1', toString(x)))
no_spaces = trimws(spaces)
```

But I am not sure how to continue this.

Can someone please show me how to proceed?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```r
id = 1:3
var= c("123 river street A1B 6L2", "124 ocean road g7u 6p2 apartment number 5", "apartment 6 k8b 7Ji"   )
my_data = data.frame(id, var)

library(stringr)
regex <- "\\b(?:\\d+[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]+\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]*(?:\\s+(?:\\d+[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]+\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]*)+\\b"
str_replace_all(my_data$var, regex, function(x) str_replace_all(x, "\\s+", ""))
## => [1] "123 river street A1B6L2"                 
## => [2] "124 ocean road g7u6p2 apartment number 5"
## => [3] "apartment 6 k8b7Ji"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C7Qs1Z/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:\d+[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]+\d)[A-Za-z\d]*` - an alphanumeric string that contains both a digit and a letter
- `(?:\s+(?:\d+[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]+\d)[A-Za-z\d]*)+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `\s+` -  one or more whitespaces
  - `(?:\d+[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]+\d)[A-Za-z\d]*` - an alphanumeric string that contains both a digit and a letter
- `\b` - word boundary.

The `function(x) str_replace_all(x, "\\s+", "")` replacement argument to `stringr::str_replace_all` replaces each match with itself but with all whitespaces removed.